# Image Rotation using Python

Tags: python, image, rotation, matplotlib, scipy

My problem is the following:
  I have two points in an image, I get the angle between these two points and rotate the image by this angle. I need to get the new position of this points in the image, but when I try to rotate those points using a rotation matrix with the same angle the points do not concur, what's wrong in the following code?

```
def rotMat(angle):
  return asarray([[cos(angle), -sin(angle)],[sin(angle),cos(angle)]])

for i in batch2:
  figure(1)
  filename = "../imagens/" + i[-1]
  outputFile = "./output/" + i[-1]
  x1 = float(i[22]) # x coordinate of first point
  y1 = float(i[23]) # y coordinate of first point
  x2 = float(i[34]) # x coordinate of second point
  y2 = float(i[35]) # y coordinate of second point

  # angle of rotation
  angle = arctan((y1-y2)/(x1-x2))

  im = imread(filename)
  im = ndimage.rotate(im, angle*180/pi, reshape=False)

  imshow(im)
  p1 = asarray([x1,y1])
  p2 = asarray([x2,y2])    

  # Rotating the points 
  # [512,680] is the center of the image
  p1n = (p1-[512,680]).dot(rotMat(angle)) + [512,680]

  p2n = (p2-[512,680]).dot(rotMat(angle)) + [512,680]

  print p1n, p2n

  plot(p1n[0],p1n[1],'d')
  plot(p2n[0],p2n[1],'d')

  savefig(outputFile)
  clf()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand 100 % what you are doing. But, did you consider that the y-axis in an image runs from 0 at the top to positive values for lower points. Therefore, the direction is opposite compared to the usual mathmetical definition. You defined `rotMat` in the usual way, but you have to adopt it to the changed y-axis in the image definition that runs in the oposite direction.

Comment: Well, thanks! The problem in fact was the translation... It should be (680,512), when I got the image shape (1024,1360,3) I forgot that 1360 is the x coordinate >.>

About the rotation matrix, the only difference is that the it will be clockwise, so I needed to use -angle